# How can I scale tick marks without scaling my function?

Tags: plotting

Take this plot for instance:

[image]

It shows power in W, but I'd like to see it in µW, so that I get 200, 400, 600,..., which is much more readable. Is there a way to do this without scaling my function and PlotRange by a factor 10$^6$?

**edit** re *szabolcs*'s comment
I already tried

```
Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[200 x, {x, 5}]}
```

but that seems to put those tick marks where they belong, namely at 200 W, 400 W, etc.(which is 240 km up the graph), not at the gridlines.

Comment: Take a look at the Ticks or FrameTicks option, and specify ticks manually.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7940/rescale-axes-e-g-change-from-hz-to-thz)

Comment: You need to specify the label and position separately.  Take a look at the `Ticks` docs.  I realize this is an inconvenient way, but unfortunately I don't have a better suggestion.

Comment: Loosely related: [About number truncation of ticks display in ListPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5276/131)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The direct way to change the labels would be to replace them.

```
pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
newTicks = AbsoluteOptions[pl, Ticks][[1, 2, 1]] /. 
     {n_, lab_?NumberQ, rest__} -> {n, 1000 lab, rest};
Show[pl, Ticks -> {newTicks, Automatic}]
```

`?NumberQ` asserts that only labeled ticks are handled.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

To achieve this, you need to set the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html) (or `FrameTicks`) option explicitly, and specify the tick positions (coordinates) and labels separately.

I'll show you how to do it using the `` CustomTicks` `` package (part of [`` LevelScheme` ``](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/)), as I find this more convenient and flexible.

```
<< CustomTicks`

μticks = LinTicks[#1, #2, TickLabelFunction -> Function[x, 1000 x]] &

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {μticks, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When using the `μticks` custom tick function I defined, the labels show 1000 times the actual value of the function.  Note that major (labelled) and minor ticks are nicely preserved without needing to do a lot of work.  This is the advantage the `` CustomTicks` `` package gave me.  Otherwise I would have had to generate these by hand.

It is based on the `LinTicks` function from the `` CustomTicks` `` package, which automatically generates ticks very similar to Mathematica's default.  I used its `TickLabelFunction` option to generate labels that are different from the actual label positions.  I was too lazy to get rid of the decimal points in the labels when they're not necessary.

Please see the docs on allowed values of the `Ticks` option.  I chose to pass it a function which generates the ticks based on the upper and lower bounds.

Comment: I agree that the ``CustomTicks` `` package is the easiest (+1). A related post (with additional installation instructions) is ["Styling ticks in a plot"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2999/245)

Answer (score 4):

Kudos to Peter - by investigating his solution, I made my own solution that might be a little more robust. The only problem with Peter's solution is that it messes up if the variables `n`, `lab`, and `rest` are already assigned.

Here's the function I wrote:

```
TickScale[plotname_, factor_] := 
 Map[Times[#, {1, If[NumberQ[#[[2]]], 1/factor, 1], {1, 1}, {1, 1}}] &,
  AbsoluteOptions[plotname, Ticks][[1, 2, 1]]  ]
```

and here's an example of how to use it:

```
f[x_] := Exp[-(x - 10^6)^2/10^5]
p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 10^6 - 2000, 10^6 + 2000}, PlotRange -> All];
Show[p1, Ticks -> {TickScale[p1, 10^6], Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x ( \[Times] 10^6 )", None}]
```

Comparison of the original plot and the plot with scaled tick marks:

[image: ScaledTicks example output]

Notice that the Mathematica is actually able to show more tick labels in the second plot since the labels are more compact.