# Frame disables Ticks in Plot and ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, frame

I stumbled upon a weird behaviour of Plot and ListLinePlot functions.

Let's plot a simple function

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Now let's say I want to extract the "Ticks" element from the plot to later on manipulate it (a good example of manipulating ticks that I found very useful is here [How can I scale tick marks without scaling my function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8358/how-can-i-scale-tick-marks-without-scaling-my-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)
 )

```
AbsoluteOptions[plot1, Ticks]
```

which gives me the ticks of the plot

```
(* {Ticks -> {{{0.,0., {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.],AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}}, .......*)
```

Now I plot the same function but add a frame

```
plot2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

but when I try to extract the Ticks element, they are gone!?

```
AbsoluteOptions[plot2, Ticks]

{Ticks -> {{}, {}}}
```

Unless I'm missing something (which is likely) this is very strange. I haven't found a fix for this issue and it's is  a problem if you want to have nice graphs with frame labels etc and also want to manipulate the Ticks.

Any help/ideas/feedback is always appreciate it.

Edit

FrameTicks also return an empty list

```
AbsoluteOptions[plot2, FrameTicks]
(*{FrameTicks -> {{}, {}, {}, {}}}*)
```

Comment: When you use a frame, Mathematica witches to FrameTicks instead of Ticks.

Comment: @MassDefect But `AbsoluteOptions[plot2, FrameTicks]` fails with `Ticks::ticks: {Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification.`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I think that's more to do with AbsoluteOptions being fundamentally broken since version 6 or thereabouts. See e.g. [AbsoluteOptions doesn't return correct option value of Ticks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97317/27951) and [More Ticks::ticks errors in AbsoluteOptions in v10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68937/27951)

Comment: Using `FullForm`on `plot2` you can convince yourself that `plot2`des not contain the tick information but only: `...Rule[Ticks, List[Automatic, Automatic]]...`

Comment: @MassDefect As Rohit pointed out it doesn't work with FrameTicks either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [More Ticks::ticks errors in AbsoluteOptions in v10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/more-ticksticks-errors-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10)

Comment: @CarlWoll It helps a lot, thank you.