# y axis multiplied with 10^-6 factor and this factor shown at the top of axis

Tags: plotting

I want to have y-axis ticks something like 1,2,3,4 but at the top of axis 10-6 should be shown in plot. This means that every tick say 1 is nothing but 1 10^-2 and 2 mean 2 10^-6 and so on. How to do this in mathematica? I use updated latest version

Comment: How about using `Ticks` and `AxesLabel` in Plot?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(7940)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7940), [(8358)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8358)

Answer (score 3):

Example solution

```
Plot[
 10^(-6)*x^2
 , {x, 1, 3}
 , Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[{10^(-6)*i, i}, {i, 0, 10, 2}]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {, "10^(-6)"}]
```

[image: Plot]