# How to Make the Tick Marks of Both Axes the Same in a 2D Plot?

Tags: plotting, ticks

In an [earlier post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnjxa.png), I asked how one can change the ratio of the units of the axes. The **easiest** way to set the ratio to one was

1- setting a `PlotRange` and
2- using the option `AspectRatio->Automatic`

However, I couldn't find any **easy** way to make the tick-marks of both axes the same! I will explain why I want such a thing.

For example, consider the following plot. As you may see, the ratio of units of the axes is one but tick marks are not the same and this deceives the observer, suggesting that it may not be a $1:1$ ratio.

So how can I make the tick marks of the $x$ axis the same as the ones for the $y$ axis, or vice versa, in the most economic way?

```
  ClearAll["Global`*"]
  f = Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 2}, {2, 2 < x <= 4}}]
  P = Plot[f, {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 2.5}}, 
        AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in ticks functions are automatically passed the range for the axis being "ticked off."  One can override this to get uniform ticking (if that's what it's called).

```
Clear[fixedTicks];
fixedTicks[min_, max_] := Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][min, max, ##3] &;

foo = Plot[Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 2}, {2, 2 < x <= 4}}], {x, 0, 4},
  Ticks -> {fixedTicks[0, 4], fixedTicks[0, 4]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 2.5}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) Just as beginner, how do you find this stuff in the documentation? :) I just read the whole page about `Ticks` and I couldn't find the thing you mentioned here! :)

Comment: and BTW, I really don't understand how the things are working in `fixedTicks` function as it is written in *Pro* style so that a *Noob* cannot get it ! :D Would you add some explanation for that or write in a simpler form, please?

Comment: @H.R. You write `fixedTicks[min, max]`, where `min` is the smallest value and `max` is the largest value. As for the rest, `ScaledTicks` is undocumented and limited knowledge is available (i.e., I don't fully understand it - I learn some things by imitation). See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104695/) and [others](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ScaledTicks); the [funny signs (links here)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/) are required, I think, (i.e., no simpler code), and a *Noob* just has to be patient and learn them to fully understand. HTH

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly specifying the tick positions may be the simplest way of getting what you want.  E.g.

```
Plot[f, {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 2.5}},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   Ticks -> {Range[0, 4, 0.5], Range[0, 2.5, 0.5]}]
```

Comment: (+1), Nice, but how about having major and minor ticks?

Comment: Mathematica help for `Tick` provides an example where this is done https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html# under "Applications"

Comment: @H. R. you might find `FindDivisions[]` to be a handy function in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that I found useful. I think that it has more compatibility in comparison with other answers and it is easy to understand for a beginner.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
TickMark[min_, max_, Inc_] := Table[
  If[IntegerQ[i],
    {i, i, .02, Black},
    {i, Null, 0.01, Black}],
   {i, Floor[min], Ceiling[max], Inc}]
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 2}, {2, 2 < x <= 4}}]
xAxis = TickMark[0, 4, 1/5];
yAxis = TickMark[0, 5/2, 1/5];
T = {xAxis, yAxis};
P = Plot[{f[x]}, {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 5/2}}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Ticks -> T, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]